# Win 10 all USB drivers failed

Tags: windows-10, usb

I've been running Win 10 happily for many months now but last night the plug was pulled on my PC and this morning no USB devices are working; they are being recognised (beeps when I plug/unplug and the correct names in Control Panel) but not one of them works.

In Control Panel all the USB devices are coming up as 'not installed' (code 28). If I delete them and attempt reinstall the Win 10 GUI notifications say that they are being reinstalled and are ready to go, but they are not and, back in Control Panel, it still thinks they are uninstalled.

If I manually look for drivers with Windows Update it says that no drivers exist (for my Dell USB Keyboard, yeah, right...).

I've tried deleting all of the USB devices AND all of the USB controllers and rebooting to let Windows reinstall them but that didn't help.

I guess something has got corrupted but where and how do I eradicate it? Not sure where I'd be if it wasn't for a spare PS2 keyboard I had lying around.

Comment: Do you know if your system uses a PCIe to USB card? If so, it could be as easy as replacing the card in question.

Comment: I can check but if the card had failed Windows wouldn't even recognise the connected devices would it? I get beeps plugging things in and unplugging them and the name that Control Panel attaches to each device is correct, so the physical USB interface must be working I guess.

Comment: The card can report the hardware IDs, which is how Windows recognises the devices. But the card cannot do any actual data flow. This is why no updates exist for the devices because the card cannot report device firmware, so the appropriate driver cannot be selected to work with said firmware.

Comment: But surely the exchange of hardware IDs is a USB protocol operation, using the USB data lines. Could a card fail such that one form of data flow works and another form of data flow doesn't?

Comment: No sign of any cards internally I'm afraid. Am I bug@#red?

Comment: To your first question, it isn't the first time this has happened. To the second question, you need to replace the Motherboard. The built-in USB Controller is dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, whaddya know, it was a February 13 2018 Microsoft update, KB4074588, which broke all of USB for me.  The workaround here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4091240/usb-devices-may-stop-working-after-installing-the-february-13-2018-upd

...which I think rolls back the update, brought them all back to life.  You Have Been Warned.

Answer (score 1):

To check if your mainboard and USB controllers are functional and to isolate the Windows corruption fault, try to boot into some stand-alone OS like [Knoppix](http://knoppix.net/) or other bootable CDs like [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/hbcd-v152/). Or at least to check if USB keyboard is functional in BIOS/UEFI config mode.

If you still find the USB subsystem non-functional, the last resort (before replacing the mobo) is to completely drain and reset BIOS, by pulling off its battery and bleeding the CMOS power to ZERO. Draining the voltage is important because brown-out conditions might leave some flip-flops in BIOS in some odd state, and they might keep the state even if the voltage rail is as low as 0.3 V.

Comment: That's a good idea: a xubuntu bootable DVD demonstrates full functionality, no mouse or keyboard issues whatsoever. So my HW is not screwed, that's good. Next question is how to make Windows happy without having to do a reinstallation. I've tried restoring to a restore point a day earlier than the failure but that hasn't helped.

Comment: And `sfc.exe /scannow` does not find in any integrity violations.

Answer (score -2):

You need to be logged on as local admin, right click on This PC and choose manage.  Open Device Manager and scroll down to Universal Serial Bus Controllers.  Right click on the USB Root Hub (or Hubs) and click on Properties.  Choose Power Management and remove the check in "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"  Reboot and see if your USB ports work.
I have seen this cause problems before.  Do this for all devices that have a "Power Management" option.
This may or may not solve your issue but it did mine.

Comment: I don't think this is applicable to OP's current situation.

Comment: I'm afraid Ultrasonic54321 is right, I tried that on all USB Root Hub devices and it didn't make a difference.